# Get Flutter State Value from Static Method

Tags: flutter

How we can get the state value from static method in flutter ? , i have one state called phone and need to use these state value in some static method.

```
String phone = '';

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPhoneString();
} 

void getPhoneString() async
{
    // basiclly just get the value from sharef pref
    setState(() {
        phone = 'myhpone-string';
    });
}

static Future<Void> Process() async {
   // get phone state value

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to use your local class variable in a static method you have two options.

1. make your variable static.
2. send your variable to the method as a parameter.

the first option is not recommended.
and for the second option you can change your static method like this:

```
static Future<Void> Process(String param) async {
   // use phone parameter

}
```

Comment: Option 2 is unable to procced, because another reason,for option i have tried to set static variable but still in static method  the value is null

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, the solution is when you call the `initState()` the page "class state" will be stored into another static value, You code will be:

```dart
String phone = '';
static phone myPhoneState;
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPhoneString();
    ***myPhoneState = this;***
} 

void getPhoneString() async
{
    // basiclly just get the value from sharef pref
    setState(() {
        phone = 'myhpone-string';
    });
}

static Future<Void> Process() async {
   // get phone state value

}
```

like this, you can call the page state and its methods whenever you want and from ever you want "Buttons, Dialogs ....."